# How to Get Model Values in DataCellTemplate() of Kendo-PivotGrid-MVC

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

```
@(Html.Kendo().PivotGrid<Models.MyModel>()
.Name("pivotgrid")
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax()
  .Transport(transport => transport.Read("ActionMethod", "Controller"))
  .Schema(schema => schema.Cube(cube => cube.Dimensions(dimensions =>
  {
      dimensions.Add(model => model.FirstName).Caption("Learner");
      dimensions.Add(model => model.CompetencyCode).Caption("Competency Codes");
      dimensions.Add(model => model.OutComeRTOCode).Caption("OutCome RTO");
      dimensions.Add(model => model.StudentId);
      dimensions.Add(model => model.GroupId);
      dimensions.Add(model => model.CompetencyId);
  })

      .Measures(measures => measures.Add("OutComeRTOCode Count").Field(model => model.OutComeRTOCode).AggregateName("Count").Field(a => a.StudentId).Field(a => a.GroupId).Field(a => a.EnrolmentId).ToString())

      ))
      .Columns(columns => { columns.Add("CompetencyCode").Expand(true); })
      .Rows(rows => rows.Add("FirstName").Expand(true))
                .Rows(rows => rows.Add("StudentId"))
                .Rows(rows => rows.Add("GroupId"))
                .Rows(rows => rows.Add("CompetencyId"))
      .Measures(measures => measures.Values("OutComeRTOCode Count")))
     .DataCellTemplate("<a onclick='GroupEnrolment(StudentId)'>#:kendo.toString(dataItem.value)#</a>")
)
```

Here in the code ,i am trying to get the StudentId in DataCellTemplate('<'a onclick='**GroupEnrolment**(*Want to Pass StudentId as Parameter here* **)**'>'#:kendo.toString(dataItem.value)#'<'/a'>').

And trying to Pass StudentId in **GroupEnrollment(StudentId)** as argument, i don't know how to get StudentId from Model and pass it to function-GroupEnrollment in anchor tag.
Or is there any other way to create a link in cells of the Kendo Pivot Grid. 
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance .

Comment: Can you try `GroupEnrolment(#= StudentId #)` in your DataCellTemplate. I am not sure but it should work.

Comment: I tried this ,but did not work.